# Getting lxml tag attributes with namespaces

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, lxml

My XML looks like:

```
...
<termEntry id="c1">
    <langSet xml:lang="de">
    ...
```

And i have the code:

```
from lxml import etree
...

for term_entry in root.iterfind('.//termEntry'):
    print term_entry.attrib['id']
    print term_entry.nsmap

    for lang_set in term_entry.iterfind('langSet'):
        print lang_set.nsmap
        print lang_set.attrib

        for some_stuff in lang_set.iterfind('some_stuff'):
            ...
```

I get the empty nsmap dict, and my attrib dict looks like `{'{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang': 'en'}`

The file may not contain `xml:` in namespace, or it may have a different namespace. How can i know what namespace used in the tag declaration? In fact, i just need to get a `lang` attribute, i don't care what namespace was used. I don't want use any crappy trash like `lang_set.attrib.values()[0]` or other lookups of a field with the known name.

Comment: Isn't finding the pair '{', '}' in the string and removing the delimited substring a simple-but-good solution for you ?

Comment: Only if there'are no other solutions. I just want to know where is stored the `{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}` string for attributes. It will be better to use `lang_set.attrib.get('{%s}lang' % namespace)`.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you're trying to do.  Can you give a more explicit example?  It seems like you already know how to request the `lang` attribute from the `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace; are you saying you also want to be able to get the `lang` attribute from other namespaces, too?  Because that doesn't necessarily make sense. But maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: "are you saying you also want to be able to get the lang attribute from other namespaces, too?" - yes. Namespaces may be different, so i just want to know their names. First time i parse file, next time i have to save a file with a similar syntax. It will not fail, if i'll save the file without namespaces, but.. It is really strange, if lxml does not provide any method for namespace processing.

Comment: Or is there a method to get the element's current namespace name with xpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *i just need to get a `lang` attribute, i don't care what namespace was used*

Your question is not very clear and you haven't provided any complete runnable code example. But doing some string manipulation as suggested by @mmgp in a comment may be enough.

However, `xml:lang` is not the same as `random_prefix:lang` (or just `lang`). I think you *should* care about the namespace. If the objective is to identify the natural language that applies to an element's content, then you should be using `xml:lang` (because that is the explicit purpose of this attribute; see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-lang-tag).

---

> *I just want to know where is stored the `{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}` string for attributes*.

It is important to know that the `xml` prefix is special. It is reserved (as opposed to almost all other namespace prefixes which are supposed to be arbitrary) and defined to be bound to `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.

From the [Namespaces in XML 1.0 W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl):

> The prefix **xml** is by definition bound to the namespace name `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. It MAY, but need not, be declared, and MUST NOT be bound to any other namespace name. Other prefixes MUST NOT be bound to this namespace name, and it MUST NOT be declared as the default namespace.

Other uses of the `xml` prefix are the `xml:space` and `xml:base` attributes.

---

> *It is really strange, if lxml does not provide any method for namespace processing*

lxml processes namespaces just fine, but [prefixes are avoided](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) as much as possible. You will need to use the `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` namespace name when doing lookups that involve the `xml` prefix.

Comment: I've made my own analog of QName that returns prefix and localname. But i don't like string operations at all. Namespace/prefix - is one entity, and localname - is another. Here they are mixed, and i have to create another interface for attribute lookups without namespaces/prefixes. As for me, the `.attrib` should be a list-based and it should contain QName() instances for attributes. And methods for lookups, i.e. `get('attr_name', namespace=None)`, that should return a value of an attribute if it exists and throw MultipleAttributesException, if attribute lookup is ambiguous.

Comment: And here we have 1) attribute prefix resolving 2) concatenation of resolved prefix and attribute name 3) parsing of the concatenated string by regexp 4) couple of problems like my question. And it's not a first question about lxml namespaces on StackOverflow. It would be simpler to have a structure for attribute storing like `a.prefix, a.namespace, a.name, a.value`. But anyway, thanks for your answer, i'll close it.

Answer (score 6):

you could simply use xpath:

```
lang_set.xpath('./@xml:lang')[0]
```

by the way, are you working with TBX files?

Comment: To me it appears that it would be more like `lang_set.xpath('./@xml:lang', namespaces={'xml':'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace'})[0]`