# How can I get Page Language (xml:lang="") using lxml library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I'm very new to lxml library and find it very confusing to parse anything but links for the moment.

I read the documents but I'm struggling to get the `xml:lang=".."` attribute's value from the top `<html ..>` tag.

How can I read that value?

Example: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting lxml tag attributes with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871925/getting-lxml-tag-attributes-with-namespaces)

Comment: I have read it. Before posting this. Frankly, I don't believe it's a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps not; retracted. The HTML parser lets you access the attribute without the full namespace, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> s = '''<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB" lang="en"></html>'''
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(s)
>>> root.get('xml:lang')
'en-GB'
```

Comment: I was trying xpath. Thank you!