# python xpath parsing of xml avoiding <lb/>

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am using xpath to parse an xml file

```py
from lxml import etree

example='''<div n="0001" type="car" xml:id="_3a327f0002">
                <p xml:id="_3a327f0003">
                1. A car is
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0004"> - big, yellow and red;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0005"> - has a big motor;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0006"> - and also has <lb/>
                      big seats.
                    </p>
                </p>
                </div>'''
```

I want to serialize the above XML file in the following way:

```
{"_3a327f0003": "1. A car is",
 "_3a327f0004":"- big, yellow and red;"
 "_3a327f0005":"- has a big motor;"
"_3a327f0006":"- and also has big seats"
```

Basically extracting the text and building a dictionary where every text belongs to his `xml:id`. My code is as follows:

```py
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, ns_clean=True)

XML_tree = etree.fromstring(example.encode() , parser=parser)
all_paras = XML_tree.xpath('.//p[@xml:id]')

list_of_paragraphs = []
for para in all_paras:
    mydict = {}
    mydict['text'] = para.text
    for att in para.attrib:
        mykey=att
        if 'id' in mykey:
            mykey='xmlid'
        mydict[mykey] = para.attrib[att]
    list_of_paragraphs.append(mydict)

PDM_XML_serializer(example)
```

It works except for the fact that if I have a node like:

```xml
<p xml:id="_3a327f0006"> - and also has <lb/>
                        big seats.
                      </p>
```

It will not extract the part from

How should I modify:

```py
XML_tree.xpath('.//p[@xml:id]')
```

in order to get all the text from <p   to /p> ?

EDIT:
para.itertext() could be used but then the first node will give back all the text of the other nodes as well.

Comment: Try to use `para.text_content()` instead of `para.text`

Comment: AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'

Comment: Have you tried *text_conten**t***?

Comment: yes... but no luck  :-(

Comment: actually when doing print(dir(para)) I get the list of the methods not including text_content

Comment: Weird, because in [docs](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) this method exists. Ah, my bad, you should use html parser `lxml.html.fromstring()`.

Comment: indeed the method is in the documentation, thats really weird

Answer (score 2):

Using `xml.etree.ElementTree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<div n="0001" type="car" xml:id="_3a327f0002">
                <p xml:id="_3a327f0003">
                1. A car is
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0004"> - big, yellow and red;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0005"> - has a big motor;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0006"> - and also has <lb/>
                      big seats.
                    </p>
                </p>
                </div>'''


def _get_element_txt(element):
    txt = element.text
    children = list(element)
    if children:
        txt += children[0].tail.strip()
    return txt


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = {p.attrib['{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id']: _get_element_txt(p)
        for p in root.findall('.//p/p')}
for k, v in data.items():
    print(f'{k} --> {v}')
```

output

```
_3a327f0004 -->  - big, yellow and red;
_3a327f0005 -->  - has a big motor;
_3a327f0006 -->  - and also has big seats.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lxml.etree` parse all elements in `all_paras` in a list/dict comprehension. Since your XML uses the special `xml` prefix and `lxml` does not yet support parsing namespace prefix in attributes (see @mzjn's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13892906/1422451)), below uses workaround with `next` + `iter` to retrieve attribute value.

Additionally, to retrieve all text values between nodes, `xpath("text()")` is used with `str.strip` and `.join` to clean up whitespace and line breaks and concatenate together.

```
from lxml import etree

example='''<div n="0001" type="car" xml:id="_3a327f0002">
                <p xml:id="_3a327f0003">
                1. A car is
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0004"> - big, yellow and red;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0005"> - has a big motor;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0006"> - and also has <lb/>
                      big seats.
                    </p>
                </p>
                </div>'''
                
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(example)
all_paras = XML_tree.xpath('.//p[@xml:id]')

output = {
    next(iter(t.attrib.values())):" ".join(i.strip() 
        for i in t.xpath("text()")).strip()
    for t in all_paras
}

output
# {
#  '_3a327f0003': '1. A car is', 
#  '_3a327f0004': '- big, yellow and red;',
#  '_3a327f0005': '- has a big motor;',
#  '_3a327f0006': '- and also has big seats.'
# }
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait, could you have a relook, I made a mistake and I forgot that there was a line missing in my desired output, since I also want the key/value pair in the dict with key "_3a327f0003", thanks

Comment: See update traversing all `<p>` in `all_paras`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lxml [itertext()](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext) to get text content of the `p` element:

```
mydict['text'] = ''.join(para.itertext())
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624062/get-all-text-inside-a-tag-in-lxml/38052404) as well for more generic solution.

Comment: This is a semi solution, since when having nested p tags the most outer tag will include the text of the inner tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

This modifies the xpath to exclude the "A car is" text as per your example. It also uses the xpath functions `string` and `normalize-space` to evaluate the `para` node as a string and join its text nodes, as well as clean up the text to match your example.

```
from lxml import etree

example='''<div n="0001" type="car" xml:id="_3a327f0002">
                <p xml:id="_3a327f0003">
                1. A car is
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0004"> - big, yellow and red;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0005"> - has a big motor;</p>
                    <p xml:id="_3a327f0006"> - and also has <lb/>
                      big seats.
                    </p>
                </p>
                </div>'''

parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False, strip_cdata=False, recover=True, ns_clean=True)

XML_tree = etree.fromstring(example.encode() , parser=parser)
all_paras = XML_tree.xpath('./p/p[@xml:id]')

list_of_paragraphs = []
for para in all_paras:
    mydict = {}
    mydict['text'] = para.xpath('normalize-space(string(.))')
    for att in para.attrib:
        mykey=att
        if 'id' in mykey:
            mykey='xmlid'
        mydict[mykey] = para.attrib[att]
    list_of_paragraphs.append(mydict)

PDM_XML_serializer(example)
```

Answer (score 0):

If these  tags are just noise for you, you can simply remove them before reading the xml

```
XML_tree = etree.fromstring(example.replace('<lb/>', '').encode() , parser=parser)
```