# manipulate with ':' in xpath attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Recently I was helping one of my friends to read docx contents and generate one new docx. I tried to make docx to zip by changing suffix, then in the 'word/document.xml' of the zip, **the attributes** like 'w:val' always have 'w:' prefix.

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse(xml_file_origin)
for index,paragraph in tree.xpath("//p[bookmarkStart[contains(@w:name, '_bookmark')]]"):
  print(paragraph)
```

then ':' will make 'XPathEvalError: Invalid expression'. I tried finding one solution in [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) but not found.

Could someone help me with how to manipulating this problem with ':' in xpath attribute

---

here the semicolon is in attribute not in element. (Sorry , I didn't get what the meaning of ‘namespace’ with 'attribute' when I receive the duplicate message). From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181888/what-does-xmlns-in-xml-mean), namespace seems to be related with **tag** (also from official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)). Could someone tell me how to use namespace with 'attribute' (with code better)?

My xml main body which I forgot to post when first open the question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xml:space="preserve">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:before="61"/>
        <w:ind w:left="383" w:right="0" w:firstLine="0"/>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="30"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:name="..." w:id="1"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr/>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_bookmark0" w:id="2"/>
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="2"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:w w:val="95"/>
          <w:sz w:val="30"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>...</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

---

Sorry for asking such a newbie question, after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871925/getting-lxml-tag-attributes-with-namespaces) and related [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871925/getting-lxml-tag-attributes-with-namespaces#comment115444376_41354188), and then print the attrib to see what it is, then I found the following solution to search '_bookmark' in attrib 'w:name' of element 'w:bookmarkStart':

```py
init_ns_ = {'w':"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"}
up_elem = tree_xml_.xpath("//w:document",namespaces=init_ns_)[0]
total_ns = up_elem.nsmap
for bookmarkname in root_.xpath('.//w:bookmarkStart/@w:name',namespaces=total_ns):
    print(bookmarkname)
```